# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError .jnilib not fond

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am having some problems with linking a jnilib in java. I receive 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ***.jnlib in java.library.path`. 
Through my research I found that this could be caused by java not knowing were the file was. So, I told it that it was in the Mac folder. I also added the file to every other folder in the project. None of this helped at all. The project is cross platform so I tried it on windows the dll's loaded just fine when I told java  to look in the windows folder. I do not understand why this would work in windows and not on a Mac. Any thoughts or ideas will be welcome.

The exception output is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libhidapi-jni-64.jnilib in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758) 
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
        at webstart.OmronIO.<init>(OmronIO.java:30)
        at webstart.Omron.main(Omron.java:13)
```

The java.library.path is: /Volumes/UNTITLED/javahidapi/mac.

The path to the jinlib is : /Volumes/UNTITLED/javahidapi/mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX, the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is used to find shared libraries (including .jnilib).  That variable is what is used to initialize java.library.path.

If you output the value of java.library.path at the point where you attempt System.loadLibrary(), you will see the list of directories searched for the library you are attempting to load.

**EDIT**

See also http://create-lab-commons.googlecode.com/svn-history/r222/trunk/java/lib/HIDAPI/README.txt, which appears to apply to the specific library you're attempting to load (hidapi), and the way you're attempting to load it (webstart).

Comment: The out put has the path to the .jnlp file. I double checked that I spelled everything correctly and that the .jnlp file was indeed in the path that was returned.

Comment: If you don't include the actual exception output, copy/paste the jnilib location, and java.library.path contents, it's impossible to say whether you're simply overlooking something or making a typo somewhere as you did in your question.  It's also possible that you have a loading issue (wrong architecture?), but those typically show up with more specific error messages.

Comment: The exception output is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libhidapi-jni-64.jnilib in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
 at webstart.OmronIO.<init>(OmronIO.java:30)
 at webstart.Omron.main(Omron.java:13)`
The java.library.path is /Volumes/UNTITLED/javahidapi/mac.The path to the jinlib is /Volumes/UNTITLED/javahidapi/mac. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Are you running via webstart?  If so, there are additional requirements for loading native libraries.  You are calling `System.loadLibrary('hidapi-jni-64')`?

Comment: At this point I am not running via webstart, just using eclipse. I am calling `System.loadLibrary("hidapi-jni-64.jnilib`.

Comment: `System.loadLibrary()` takes the name of the library (not its filename), which in this case is "hidapi-jni-64".

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried your suggestion however, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Silly me naming conventions are important. I was not adding the lib prefix to the file name. Thanks so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. It was not loading library file in any path, even after using - Djava.library.path in application argument. I am using `System.loadLibrary("test")`. The library name was `libtest.jnilib`
The prefix and suffix will be added while executing.

I am using Mac M1 Pro. Unfortunately, it is not supported in ARM based JDKs. Switching to non-ARM JDK solved the issue.